# Returns en if-else

Tags: c

es lenguaje c, pero se aplicaría a todos los lenguajes. El caso es que siempre tengo la función y dentro tengo por ejemplo bucles, se me hace dificil el visualizar un return utilizando bucles if else (en general creo que tengo dudas con todos). Pongo este ejemplo de una función void, pero me gustaría cambiarlo por un int, y cambiar tal vez los parámetros (argumentos) de la función. Espero que podaís ayudarme a entenderlo, si podeís modificar este código para hacer ejemplos con los bucles (if-else, for, while) o si preferís con cualquier ejemplo sería genial. Sé utilizarlos, pero no me queda muy claro lo del return en los if-else.

```
void contar(FILE *fp, int opcion_l, int opcion_w, int opcion_c){
    int state, nw, nl,nc,c;
    state = OUT;
    nw=nc=nl=0;
    if(opcion_l == 1){
            while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
                    if(c=='\n')
                            ++nl;
            }
            printf("%d\n",nl);
    }else if(opcion_c == 1){
            while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
                    ++nc;
            }
            printf("%d\n",nc);
    }else{
            while((c =getchar()) != EOF){
                    if(c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
                            state = OUT;
                    else if(state == OUT){
                            state = IN;
                            ++nw;
                    }
            }
            printf("%d\n",nw);
   }
```

}

Gracias.

Comment: Es complicado escribir 7 párrafos de forma tan densa como lo has hecho tu. En tu código no hay un solo `return`... ¿cual es tu problema? No veo una sola pregunta en el texto. Por favor, replantea la situación y pon un ejemplo que ilustre tu problema con claridad.

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino que lo que quieres hacer es devolver un valor resultado de la función, en vez de usar printf. Podria ser así:

```
int contar(FILE *fp, int opcion_l, int opcion_w, int opcion_c){
    int state, nw, nl,nc,c;
    state = OUT;
    nw=nc=nl=0;
    if(opcion_l == 1){
            while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
                    if(c=='\n')
                            ++nl;
            }
            return (nl);    //  printf("%d\n",nl);
    }else if(opcion_c == 1){
            while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
                    ++nc;
            }
            return (nc);   //  printf("%d\n",nc);
    }else{
            while((c =getchar()) != EOF){
                    if(c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
                            state = OUT;
                    else if(state == OUT){
                            state = IN;
                            ++nw;
                    }
            }
            return (nw); //  printf("%d\n",nw);
   }
```

Una vez que la opción se ha seleccionado, y se realiza un bucle, el resultado se devuelve con `return`